# Redis incrementing a numeric value - ERR value is not an integer or out of range

Tags: redis, key-value, redis-cli

Redis `incr` function behaves erratically. When trying to increment any positive integer key that has not been set yet, it results in the following error. However, when first setting it by `set` then incrementing using `incr` for the same key, the problem is no longer there. Any reason why it behaves this way? Any workarounds?

```
127.0.0.1:6379[5]> incr 100
(error) ERR value is not an integer or out of range
127.0.0.1:6379[5]> incr '100'
(error) ERR value is not an integer or out of range
127.0.0.1:6379[5]> incr "100"
(error) ERR value is not an integer or out of range
127.0.0.1:6379[5]> set 100 1
OK
127.0.0.1:6379[5]> incr 100
(integer) 2
```

This behavior is only true when incrementing non-existing Integer keys:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get "ahmedov"
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379> incr "ahmedov"
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> incr "ahmedov"
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> get 12.1
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379> incr 12.1
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> get -1
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379> incr -1
(integer) 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Until you had actually called the `SET` command, you were trying to increment a key named '100' that did not contain a valid representation of an integer number.

After setting the key called '100' to the string "1", the increment succeeds and returns 2 (1+1) as expected.

Comment: But when I type: incr "Ahmedov" for example, without calling Set first, I don't get that error.

Comment: That's also expected - calling `INCR` on a nonexisting key implicitly initializes its value to 0. IIRC, this is well referenced in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java and Spring Boot, here is how you can do it:

Declare an attribute of the class `StringRedisTemplate`, for example:

```java
private final StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate;
```

You have two options:

1. Set and increment

```java
String key = "a";
int value = 3;
redisTemplate.boundValueOps(key).set(String.valueOf(value));
Long turn = redisTemplate.boundValueOps(key).increment(); // -> 4
```

2. Increment

You can also increment without setting a value first, in this case the first value will be 1:

```java
String otherKey = "b";
Long turn = redisTemplate.boundValueOps(otherKey).increment(); // -> 1
```

You can find a complete example [here](https://github.com/julianespinel/noq/blob/main/src/main/java/com/jespinel/noq/turns/TurnNumberService.java#L23)

Answer (score 0):

Please use StringRedisTemplate instead of RedisTemplate for increment operation. Since the 'icrement()' method is a String based activity, it is recommended to use StringRedisTemplate. Please find the sample below.

Define StringRedisTemplate

```
    @Bean
public StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate = new StringRedisTemplate();
    stringRedisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    // Add some specific configuration here. Key serializers, etc.
    return stringRedisTemplate;
}
```

Set increment key with initial value

```
@Autowired
private StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate;

stringRedisTemplate.opsForValue().set("key", "100");
```

Get increment

```
Long increment = stringRedisTemplate.opsForValue().increment("key");
```

Result

```
increment is :101
```

This is verified & working, lets code...